# How to sort / display Reviews based on rating - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, review, product-review

I want to display reviews but by sorting them (displaying the highest rating to the lowest rating).

This is how I got the reviews for each product

```
// Get reviews for each product
    public function getReviewCollection($productId){
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
        $collection = $this->_reviewCollection->create()
            ->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
            )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $productId
            )->setDateOrder()
            ->addRateVotes();

        return $collection->getItems(); //Get all review data of product
    }
```

In my phtml file:

```
$reviews = $block->getReviewCollection($_item->getID());
if (count($reviews) > 0) {
    foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
        foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) {
            $ratings[] = $vote->getPercent();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I sort the reviews based on the $ratings?